# What is the difference in plots features between analytic (holomorphic) and non-analytic functions?

Tags: plotting, complex

We know `FunctionAnalytic` can check whether a complex function is analytic. But I want to use `ComplexPlot3D` or `ComplexPlot` to plot the complex function and see whether it is an analytic function (Holomorphic function). Or in other words, what is the difference between analytic and non-analytic functions in the function plots? I know that the argument 'jumps' and singularities are obvious features of non-analytic functions, but are there any other features of non- analytic functions besides these?

For example, the following complex function is non-analytic, but it does not seem to observe the argument 'jumps' or singularities in its `ComplexPlot3D` or `ComplexPlot`, are there any other features in the plots that can determine whether it is a non-analytical function? **Or can we observe non-analytical features by setting options in `ComplexPlot3D` or `ComplexPlot`?**

I'm not sure if there is an answer to this question.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

w[x_, y_] := x^2 + I y^2;

FunctionAnalytic[w[x, y], {x, y}]

(*False*)

w[z_] := FullSimplify[w[x, y] /. {x -> (z + Conjugate[z])/2, y -> (z - Conjugate[z])/(2 I)}, 
  Element[x | y, Reals]];

FunctionSingularities[w[z], z]

(*True*)

ComplexPlot3D[w[z], {z, -8 - 8 I, 8 + 8 I}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]

ComplexPlot[w[z], {z, -8 - 8 I, 8 + 8 I}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: I think the only general criterion is if the Taylor series converge to the function in the vicinity of a point. Even a smooth function, where all derivatives exist everywhere,  not need to be analytical. A simple example is Exp[-1/x] that is not analytical at x=0.

Comment: There is none.  Every continuous function on a compact set can be uniformly approxomated with polynomials (analytic functions), see [Weierstrass theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html), i.e. a continuous function on a compact set (closed and bounded) can be approximated as close as you like with a polynomial, one can set $\epsilon=10^{-20}$ and they could non be distinguished.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This issue is raised because MMA examples often compare the images of analytic and non analytic functions together, and there are many options in `ComplexPlot3D` and `ComplexPlot` that can highlight features of complex functions.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the concepts of real analytic and complex analytic are different.

```
FunctionAnalytic[Conjugate[z],z]
(*True*)
FunctionAnalytic[Conjugate[z],z,Complexes]
(*False*)
```

Complex analytic functions are more rigid in certain sense and they give conformal mappings, i.e. map right angles to right angles when $f'(z)\neq 0$.

```
showMapping[fun_,th_:0,max_:10] :=
    ContourPlot[ReIm[Exp[I th] fun/.{z->x+I y}],{x,-max,max},{y,-max,max},ContourShading->None];
```

(the parameter `th` will be explained later.)

For example, $z^{2}$ gives

[image]

For the OP's example, the correct code is,

```
w[x_,y_] :=
    x^2 + I y^2;
w[z_] :=
    w[x,y]/.{x->1/2 (z+Conjugate[z]),y->-(1/2) I (z-Conjugate[z])}//Simplify

w[z]
showMapping[w[z]]
```

we need to add a phase factor $\exp(i\theta)$ to detect the failure of non-conformality,
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really good. Your graph was obtained using the CR-equation of an analytic function, which is known as conjugation. I have done it before, but I think it is an indirect method. My original intention in raising this question was to directly plot f (z) using `ComplexPlot3D` or `ComplexPlot`, highlighting a feature of the complex function by setting options to identify analytical and non analytical functions. @Lacia

Comment: @lotus2019 There are many ways of losing analyticity - mixing of holomorphic and anti-holomorphic dependencies, different kinks of singularities, discontinuities and branch cut.... some of them are local properties, some are global properties. I don't think `ComplexPlot` is the proper way to get intuitions of analyticity. btw there is a missing `I` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, the code error has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Holomorpic functions are functions of two arguments. If x and i y both are complexified we are in $\mathbb R^4$. The fact, that they are  independents of the 45° diagonal $x- I y$ and then considered as a function of one complex variable $x+iy$ in the real 2d submanifold cannot made visible, its differential topology in $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C = \mathbb R^4$

Comment: I do not believe that this answers the original question.

Comment: Plain: No? In Reality, its not possible to "see" a difference between a vector field ReIm @f (z), that has rot=0 and div=0 and a more general field., because the differences are "visible" by these specialized derivatives only. These kind of properties are are the field of sequences of maps between five vector spaces $z \to  f(z) \to df(z)  \to d*df(z) \to 0$